# Minus sign vs dash for negative numbers in siunitx

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

When I enter negative unit numbers using `siunitx`, they are printed with a long dash, rather than slightly different minus sign which I would like to print. Maybe it's possible to modify the settings in `sisetup` to fix this, but I can't find anything on this topic in the package manual.

I also see that the minus in math mode also looks the same (like a long dash), so maybe the math font is an issue?

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{isomath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    separate-uncertainty,
    repeatunits=false,
    detect-family,
    unit-mode=text,
}

\SI{-80}{\celsius}
$-80$
```

Comment: You want to replace the minus sign with a hyphen???

Comment: The output you get is the expected one. typically, the minus sign is longer than a hyphen.

Comment: Oh, for some reason I assumed that the output I was receiving was a dash, rather than a minus sign, but I think you're right. Thanks

Comment: I voted for closing because the output of the OP's example shows exactly the same symbol for the minus sign in both instances, so it's not clear what the question is asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the output of the OP's example shows exactly the same symbol for the minus sign in both instances, so it's not clear what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bernard and @leandriis have pointed out in there comments, the hyphen and the minus are two glyphs that are different from each other. In the past however, due to lack of storage space and other factors, both signs where used equally, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs for instance.

Nowadays however you have the choice between the mathematical minus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs or the hyphen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen, which by itself has multiple uses and ways of getting represented.